# how can I get logo of curent comoany in openERP and us it in webkit Report

Tags: webkit, report, odoo

how can I get logo of curent comoany in openERP and us it in webkit Report without pass the name of Imge to mako file

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${company.logo}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using base_report_designer module ? If it is so, You need to add your company logo in Company form, There is a field to add a logo at top of the Company form. Add it and Save it.

If you are creating a report by Report Designer plugin, After creating a report, when you will click on Send to the Server button, in that wizard, You need to tick 'Corporate Header' option during sending to OpenERP. By doing this, You will be able to see in report from OpenERP.

I am assuming that you are using base_report_designer module.

Comment: Iam using webkit report not Report Designer for that i wont to get logo of curent company and use it in mako file like this      <td>${company.logo_web |entity}</td>

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
${helper.embed_image('png', company.logo, 145, 35)|n}
```

Where 145 is the width and 35 is the height. The statement above will create an `<img/>` tag for you.